# Android studio Merge Trace.beginSection() and endSection() to get total time

Tags: android-studio, trace, android-profiler

I want to improve some part of my app and put `Trace.beginSection("MyLable");` and `Trace.endSection();` to see time of wrapped methods.

But i got these problems:

1. First can not see my custom label in profiler.
2. Second is i wan to merg `Trace.beginSection` and `Trace.endSection` as a single item so i can calculate wrapped methods time.

[image]

I tried this  in **Call Chart** and **Flame Chart** view but result was the same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @XueQing Nope :(

Answer (score 1):

How about measuring the duration of the trace?

```
long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
Trace.beginSection("someLabel");

/* do stuff */

long endMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
Trace.endSection();

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trace duration: " + (endMs - startMs) + "ms");
```

Also see [systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace) and [Generate Trace Logs by Instrumenting Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/generate-trace-logs).

Android Q adds four new methods to [Trace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace), but nothing that would tell the duration.

Since Android P, there's [systrace on device](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-on-device) available.

Comment: I know i can use it with Log, but i wann achive it with Profiler. As you now there is time for all methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you`ll trace your app with Perfetto, those traces can be browsed through the UI, and exact time can be displayed, with no manual time calculations.

How to run Perfetto traces you can see [here](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing#recording-a-trace-through-the-cmdline)

Here is an example of a function wrapped with the label "*MyLable*".

[image]

In the top you can inject the label to search.
Block with your trace will be placed in the row with your application.
If you click on that you`ll see more details in the panel below. *in my example function took 44 microseconds*